# Wordpress admin interface takes forever to load

Tags: wordpress

TLDR Version : Wordpress admin interface does not load

I have a WordPress blog, I have been using it for over 2 years.

Recently I have been experiencing this problem. Al pages login, add new post, dashboard i.e all admin interface pages take forever to load.

I tried debugging this problem, below is a network stat info from my firebug.

[image]

It seems that my wp-admin.min.css takes a lot time to load.

Also then I reliased may be this has something to do with the Wordpress Latest Update I had done. But I am not sure, how do i fix this ?

I have search a lot on this, but just couldn't find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be your WordPress installation at all (but rather something about your own internet connection or machine setup).  The login page loaded very quickly for me, and [here you can see a complete analysis from Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/oswX8M0zZ/http://yassershaikh.com/wp-login.php).

It took less than half a second to load.  I would try a few of these things to narrow down on the problem:

- Reboot
- Try a different browser
- Try a different computer
- Try a different network / location

Comment: yep... something seems to be wrong with my internet connection I am using. I tried loading the `wp-admin.php` page on my mobile using my mobile data plan and it also loaded in less than a second.